# How to access javax/persistence/ from client?

Tags: jpa, jakarta-ee, classpath

When running `java hwai.Main` from directory `target/classes`, I get an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/Persistence
at hwai.Main.main(Main.java:17)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.persistence.Persistence
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
...
```

I get the same error when I'm running `java hwai.Main` from directory `target/test1/WEB-INF/classes`
This is my project structure after running `mvn package glassfish:redeploy`:

```
├── pom.xml
├── src
│   └── main
│       ├── java
│       │   ├── hwai
│       │   │   ├── helloWorld.java
│       │   │   ├── helloWorldResource.java
│       │   │   ├── Main.java
│       │   │   ├── StudentPOJO.java
│       │   │   ├── StudentRest.java
│       │   │   └── Todo.java
│       │   └── META-INF
│       │       └── persistence.xml
│       └── webapp
│           ├── index.html
│           └── WEB-INF
│               └── web.xml
└── target
    ├── classes
    │   └── hwai
    │       ├── helloWorld.class
    │       ├── helloWorldResource.class
    │       ├── Main.class
    │       ├── StudentPOJO.class
    │       ├── StudentRest.class
    │       └── Todo.class
    ├── generated-sources
    │   └── annotations
    ├── maven-archiver
    │   └── pom.properties
    ├── maven-status
    │   └── maven-compiler-plugin
    │       └── compile
    │           └── default-compile
    │               ├── createdFiles.lst
    │               └── inputFiles.lst
    ├── test1
    │   ├── index.html
    │   ├── META-INF
    │   └── WEB-INF
    │       ├── classes
    │       │   └── hwai
    │       │       ├── helloWorld.class
    │       │       ├── helloWorldResource.class
    │       │       ├── Main.class
    │       │       ├── StudentPOJO.class
    │       │       ├── StudentRest.class
    │       │       └── Todo.class
    │       ├── lib
    │       │   ├── commonj.sdo-2.1.1.jar
    │       │   ├── eclipselink-2.7.0.jar
    │       │   ├── javax.json-1.0.4.jar
    │       │   ├── javax.persistence-2.0.0.jar
    │       │   └── validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar
    │       └── web.xml
    └── test1.war
```

Searching the internet, I found [Eclipse Warnings: class javax.persistence.* not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24812730/eclipse-warnings-class-javax-persistence-not-found) and [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/Persistence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850850/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-persistence-persistence/16131823), but neither helped me. I'm quite a javaee newbie.

`pom.xml` contains among others

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

The `import` - statement in Main.java is

```
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
```

Comment: You need to learn about the classpath. Any library you're using must be in the classpath, otherwise Java can't possibly find the classes your code is using. This is Java fundamental stuff. Learn the basics before doing complex stuff like Maven and JPA. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html

Comment: Thanks! Calling `java -cp "./:../lib/*" hwai.Main` from dir `target/test1/WEB-INF/classes` did the trick... Now I get `No Persistence provider for EntityManager named ...` which might result from misplaced persistence.xml (though I put it in the classpath), but that's another story...

Comment: `mkdir -p target/test1/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF` and `cp persistence.xml target/test1/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF` helped, after reading https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3230798/eclipselink-no-persistence-provider-for-entitymanager-named